# Counting the number of ways to form teams

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Here's the Question,

12 employees are eligible for working on a company's project. The team must consist of 4 people. However, two employees had a fight and refuse to work together. How many ways can the team be formed?

So I am having a hard time checking/confirming if my thinking behind this is correct, even when looking at exclusion-inclusions principles. So I will explain what I think is right and hopefully someone can confirm the logic.

1) $^{12}C_4$ is the total number of ways of selecting a team of 4. 
   $^{10}C_2$ is the total number of ways to exclude the 2 people being together. $^{12}C_4 - ^{10}C_2 =450$ possible ways.

2) Excluding 1 of the two leaves $^{11}C_4$ possible choices.
   Excluding the other 1 instead is also $^{11}C_4$ possible choices. However, this over counts the 10 other people in both cases which is $^{10}C_4$ choices. Therefore $2 \times ^{11}C_4 - ^{10}C_4 = 450$ possible ways.

I know the answer of 450 is right, but I am unsure if my reasoning behind these calculations is correct. Maybe there is another way to look at this problem that is easier to grasp?

Many Thanks

Ken

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I'd think of the reasoning in (1) as $^{10}C_2$ being the number of teams that *force* the two fighting employees to be together (with 2 team members left to pick), not the number of ways to exclude them. These are the "bad teams" we need to subtract off from the total number of teams.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo That makes more sense for 1) We want to exclude undesirable options. It's not the anti-option as how I looked at it.

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can produce $\times$ by typing `$\times$`; you can produce $\cdot$ by typing `$\cdot$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am familiar with latex, but I didn't like either so I just used a text x. Thank you for the comment though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method is an elegant way to solve the problem.

Here is another approach.  Observe that either exactly one of the two feuding employees is placed on the team or neither one is.

*Exactly one of the two feuding employees is placed on the team*:  We choose which of the two feuding employees is placed on the team and which three of the other ten employees is placed on the team with that person, which can be done in $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{3}$$ ways.

*Neither of the two feuding employees is placed on the team*:  We must choose which four of the other ten employees is placed on the team, which can be done in $$\binom{10}{4}$$ ways.

*Total*:  Since these two cases are mutually exclusive, the number of ways the team of four employees can be chosen without placing the two feuding employees together is 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4} = 450$$
as you found.

Comment: I love this answer, particularly because I am trying to grasp the concept of mutually exclusive and this answer includes that view. I am also looking at collectively exhaustive while also taking into account the 4 different types of arrangements, but that's another story entirely.

Comment: As a check, observe that there are $\binom{12}{4}$ ways to select four employees without restriction, $\binom{2}{2}\binom{10}{2}$ ways to choose a group with both feuding employees, $\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose a group with exactly one of the feuding employees, and $\binom{2}{0}\binom{10}{4}$ ways to choose a group with neither feuding employee.  Observe that $\binom{12}{4} = \binom{2}{2}\binom{10}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{3} + \binom{2}{0}\binom{10}{4}$.